# Get all posts from specific category on wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

here is my code i want all posts from specific category through WP Query

```
$wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT * 
      FROM rxt_posts 
     WHERE post_status = 'publish' 
       AND post_type = 'post' 
     ORDER 
        BY post_date DESC
    ")
```

my category id 22
my vategory name "Videos"

please help me how to add category id and get all posts

Comment: You would use a WP_Query object for that. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/161071/wp-query-by-category-name

Comment: I dont understand that code can you edit my code so i can easily paste there please

Comment: Sounds like you're just trying to display the posts, and not iterate to make your own template. If that's true, I'd suggest using the WP shortcode that I put in my answer below. :)

Comment: Did you every try the code?

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
    'cat'    => 22,
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Then you would iterate over the object with this basic code:

```
if ( $loop->have_posts() ) : ?> 
  *** This is creating an array of post that match the args (cat id=22) ***
  <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
  *** this is where you'd add the code for each post
  <?php endwhile ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

Based on your information, I'd say you just want to *display* the posts somewhere. If so, you can easily use the WP shortcode to do that. Documentation is here: https://wordpress.com/support/display-posts-shortcode/

You would just use the slug instead of the id number. :)

`[display-posts category="category-slug-here"]`